# Windows to Linux script issues: "IndexError: list index out of range"

Tags: python, linux, windows, csv, ubuntu

I have a script - works perfectly in Windows, but when I tried running it in Ubuntu it spat out the error message:

> IndexError: list index out of range.

It's a pretty simple script: it imports a `CSV` file, reads the rows, prints the first item in each row into a list, uses `set()` to remove duplicates, then writes this new list to a file.

```
import csv, glob

for x in glob.glob("*raw_vcf.csv"):
   csv_f = open(x, "r")

data = [c for c in csv.reader(csv_f)]
frags_unique = []

def frag_list(vcf_data, uniquefrags):
    """ 
    User input: an imported .vcf file (='vcf_import'); an empty list
    (= 'uniquefrags').
    'frag_list' takes 'vcf_import', reads each row/list, taking the first item
    and attaching only unique values to 'uniquefrags', using the set() function.
    First row (header row) in 'vcf_data' is deleted; not needed.
    """
    del vcf_data[0]
    list_1 = []
    for row in vcf_data:
        list_1.append(row[0])
    for item in list(set(list_1)):
        uniquefrags.append(item)

frag_list(data, frags_unique)

out = open("output_unique_frags.txt","w")
for frags in frags_unique:
    out.write(frags+"\n")
out.close()
```

Specifically, the error occurs in the module:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PRIME_unique_frags.py", line 50, in <module>
    frag_list(data, frags_unique)
  File "PRIME_unique_frags.py", line 46, in frag_list
    list_1.append(row[0])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

But I honestly can't see what is wrong with it, given it works on my Windows OS; tried rewriting it in different ways but no luck.

Some sample input data ("*_raw_vcf.csv"):

```
A,B,C,D,E
1,2,3,4,5
1,5,4,3,2
2,3,4,5,6
2,3,4,7,8
3,4,5,6,7
```

Should in theory (and does in Windows) produce a file ("output_unique_frags.txt"; the unique values in column A):

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: use a debugger, or the print statement to find out what's the value of row on linux. then you can determine why you get the IndexError. I think @warvariuc's answer is pretty close to the point, though

Comment: use a print statement after frag_unique=[] like print csv_f to see which csv is being read and another print after del vcf_data[0] use print del vcf_data see and say what is being printed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hey everyone, thanks for feedback!**

---

Just briefly in response to some comments made: I made very sure that there was only one occurrence of "*raw_vcf.csv", such that,

```
for x in glob.glob("*raw_vcf.csv"):
   csv_f = open(x, "r")
```

Would only pull up one file - and I tested this to make sure it would work.

---

**SOLUTION**

After the suggestions about the list being empty, I checked it:

[image]

It wasn't obvious when I had asked for print row[0] (for rows in data), but when printing the list, I noted an extra ENTER in the data file which was being read in as a blank line (last element in the list: '[]'). This is what was throwing it off because .append() won't add nothing.

So again thanks for the comments. In hindsight it was a kinda simple problem, but as I am still very new to Python, interpreting the jargon can be a tad challenging. Appreciate everyone who offered suggestions and helped me learn for next time.

Comment: Ah yes, the inadvertent blank line at the end - I've hit this one myself. Glad you got it sorted, and learnt something in the process...

Answer (score 3):

The Traceback is saying that `row` has no element`[0]`, so it's an empty list. This suggests that on the Ubuntu system the reader is returning an empty list for each row.

Have a look at the [csv docs](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/csv.html#csv.reader); you can specify a dialect when you set up the reader. I'd say that the reader on the Ubuntu system is looking for a different delimiter that the one in the file.

BTW: Is the indentation above code correct? There's a few odd things going on there if so, eg:

```
for x in glob.glob("*raw_vcf.csv"):
   csv_f = open(x, "r")
```

If there's more than one .csv file, you're only going to get the last one.

Comment: 1 you are going to get only the last one

Answer (score 3):

Looks like line endings are not the culprit:

```
Python 2.7.8 (default, Oct 20 2014, 15:05:19) 
[GCC 4.9.1] on linux2
>>> a = """A,B,C,D,E
... 1,2,3,4,5
... 1,5,4,3,2
... 2,3,4,5,6
... 2,3,4,7,8
... 3,4,5,6,7"""
>>> with open('1.csv', 'w') as f:
...     f.write(a.replace('\n', '\r\n'))
... 
>>> import csv
>>> list(csv.reader(open('1.csv', "r")))
[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], ['1', '5', '4', '3', '2'], ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6'], ['2', '3', '4', '7', '8'], ['3', '4', '5', '6', '7']]
```

Another guess is that here is the problem:

```
for x in glob.glob("*raw_vcf.csv"):
   csv_f = open(x, "r")
```

This open last file in the directory with mask `"*raw_vcf.csv"`. I guess you have more than one file to process. On Windows you get one file, on Linux it could be another malformed file.

You should debug the issue. Print the file name used to open the file.

**Old answer:**

The [docs say](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.lineterminator):

> Note The reader is hard-coded to recognise either `'\r'` or `'\n'` as
>   end-of-line, and ignores `lineterminator`. This behavior may change in
>   the future.

I suppose the CSV file was created in Windows having `\r\n` as line terminator. So the reader under Linux finds empty lines because of this.

Solution (untested, taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2314565/248296)):

```
csv_f = open(filename, 'rtU')
```